# Geotools shapefile and geotiff displaying problem in JMapPane

Tags: shapefile, java, geotiff-tiff, geotools

I'm trying to get a JMapPane to show up in a JPanel, but without success. Below is the JPanel instance containing the map. I am importing a geotiff and a shapefile layered in that order. Not only does the geotiff raster layer not show up, but the shapefile is displayed backwards. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Screenshot]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import org.geotools.coverage.GridSampleDimension;
import org.geotools.coverage.grid.GridCoverage2D;
import org.geotools.coverage.grid.io.AbstractGridFormat;
import org.geotools.coverage.grid.io.GridCoverage2DReader;
import org.geotools.coverage.grid.io.GridFormatFinder;
import org.geotools.data.FileDataStore;
import org.geotools.data.FileDataStoreFinder;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureSource;
import org.geotools.factory.CommonFactoryFinder;
import org.geotools.map.FeatureLayer;
import org.geotools.map.GridReaderLayer;
import org.geotools.map.Layer;
import org.geotools.map.MapContent;
import org.geotools.styling.ChannelSelection;
import org.geotools.styling.ContrastEnhancement;
import org.geotools.styling.RasterSymbolizer;
import org.geotools.styling.SLD;
import org.geotools.styling.SelectedChannelType;
import org.geotools.styling.Style;
import org.geotools.styling.StyleFactory;
import org.geotools.swing.JMapPane;
import org.opengis.filter.FilterFactory2;
import org.opengis.style.ContrastMethod;

public class MapImagePanel extends JPanel {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -7924289582676785758L;
private File blueMarble = null;
private File borderShape = null;
private GridCoverage2DReader gridCoverage2DReader;
private StyleFactory styleFactory = CommonFactoryFinder.getStyleFactory();

public StyleFactory getStyleFactory() {
    return styleFactory;
}

private FilterFactory2 ff = CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory2();

public MapImagePanel() {
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    this.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(720, 360));

    try {
        this.setBlueMarble(new File(this.getClass().getResource("/gis/BlueMarbleNG_2004-12-01_rgb_720x360.tiff").toURI()));
    } catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        this.setBorderShape(new File(this.getClass().getResource("/gis/world_borders/TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.shp").toURI()));
    } catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        this.displayLayers();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void displayLayers() throws Exception {
    AbstractGridFormat format = GridFormatFinder.findFormat(this.getBlueMarble());
    this.setGridCoverageReader(format.getReader(this.getBlueMarble()));

    Style rgbStyle = this.createRGBStyle();

    // connect to the shapefile
    FileDataStore dataStore = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(this.getBorderShape());
    SimpleFeatureSource shapefileSource = dataStore.getFeatureSource();

    Style shpStyle = SLD.createPolygonStyle(Color.BLUE, null, 0.0f);

    final MapContent map = new MapContent();
    map.setTitle("LogMap");

    Layer rasterLayer = new GridReaderLayer(this.getGridCoverageReader(), rgbStyle);
    map.addLayer(rasterLayer);

    Layer shpLayer = new FeatureLayer(shapefileSource, shpStyle);
    map.addLayer(shpLayer);

    JMapPane mapPane = new JMapPane();
    mapPane.setMapContent(map);
    //mapPane.setDisplayArea(shapefileSource.getBounds());
    mapPane.setDisplayArea(this.getGridCoverageReader().getOriginalEnvelope());

    this.add(mapPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

// docs start create rgb style
/**
 * This method examines the names of the sample dimensions in the provided
 * coverage looking for "red...", "green..." and "blue..." (case insensitive
 * match). If these names are not found it uses bands 1, 2, and 3 for the
 * red, green and blue channels. It then sets up a raster symbolizer and
 * returns this wrapped in a Style.
 *
 * @return a new Style object containing a raster symbolizer set up for RGB
 *         image
 */
private Style createRGBStyle() {
    GridCoverage2DReader reader = this.getGridCoverageReader();
    StyleFactory sf = this.getStyleFactory();
    GridCoverage2D cov = null;
    try {
        cov = reader.read(null);
    } catch (IOException giveUp) {
        throw new RuntimeException(giveUp);
    }
    // We need at least three bands to create an RGB style
    int numBands = cov.getNumSampleDimensions();
    if (numBands < 3) {
        return null;
    }
    // Get the names of the bands
    String[] sampleDimensionNames = new String[numBands];
    for (int i = 0; i < numBands; i++) {
        GridSampleDimension dim = cov.getSampleDimension(i);
        sampleDimensionNames[i] = dim.getDescription().toString();
    }
    final int RED = 0, GREEN = 1, BLUE = 2;
    int[] channelNum = { -1, -1, -1 };
    // We examine the band names looking for "red...", "green...",
    // "blue...".
    // Note that the channel numbers we record are indexed from 1, not 0.
    for (int i = 0; i < numBands; i++) {
        String name = sampleDimensionNames[i].toLowerCase();
        if (name != null) {
            if (name.matches("red.*")) {
                channelNum[RED] = i + 1;
            } else if (name.matches("green.*")) {
                channelNum[GREEN] = i + 1;
            } else if (name.matches("blue.*")) {
                channelNum[BLUE] = i + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    // If we didn't find named bands "red...", "green...", "blue..."
    // we fall back to using the first three bands in order
    if (channelNum[RED] < 0 || channelNum[GREEN] < 0
            || channelNum[BLUE] < 0) {
        channelNum[RED] = 1;
        channelNum[GREEN] = 2;
        channelNum[BLUE] = 3;
    }
    // Now we create a RasterSymbolizer using the selected channels
    SelectedChannelType[] sct = new SelectedChannelType[cov
            .getNumSampleDimensions()];
    ContrastEnhancement ce = sf.contrastEnhancement(this.ff.literal(1.0),
            ContrastMethod.NORMALIZE);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        sct[i] = sf.createSelectedChannelType(
                String.valueOf(channelNum[i]), ce);
    }

    RasterSymbolizer sym = sf.getDefaultRasterSymbolizer();
    ChannelSelection sel = sf.channelSelection(sct[RED], sct[GREEN],
            sct[BLUE]);
    sym.setChannelSelection(sel);

    return SLD.wrapSymbolizers(sym);
}

public File getBorderShape() {
    return borderShape;
}

public void setBorderShape(File borderShape) {
    this.borderShape = borderShape;
}

public File getBlueMarble() {
    return blueMarble;
}

public void setBlueMarble(File blueMarble) {
    this.blueMarble = blueMarble;
}

public GridCoverage2DReader getGridCoverageReader() {
    return gridCoverage2DReader;
}

public void setGridCoverageReader(GridCoverage2DReader gridCoverage2DReader) {
    this.gridCoverage2DReader = gridCoverage2DReader;
}

}
```

**UPDATE**

Added a few lines and now have the shapefile borders showing up correctly, but the geotiff is still missing.

Under the displayLayers() method I added:

```
...
mapPane.setMapContent(map);
mapPane.setDisplayArea(shapefileSource.getBounds());
...
```

This is the result:
[image: working shapefile]

Comment: What projection is the raster in?

Comment: Viewing the metadata in QGIS, it reports Latitude/Longitude projection with a WGS84 datum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work for me - I'm using the [Admin Boundaries](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/) from [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/) and a [Blue Marble jpeg](http://visibleearth.nasa.gov/view.php?id=74218) (with a [hand cranked world file](https://github.com/ianturton/geotools-cookbook/blob/master/data/world.200412.3x21600x10800.jpw))  and this [code](https://github.com/ianturton/geotools-cookbook/blob/master/modules/input/src/main/java/org/ianturton/cookbook/input/SaveMapAsImage.java) which gives me this image.

Without seeing your actual datafiles my suspicion is that you have a tiff file with either no world file or a broken one instead of a geotiff. If that is the case then you should be seeing some sort of error message on the console.

[image: map of the world]

Comment: I've been using the Blue Marble tiffs from http://www.unearthedoutdoors.net/global_data/true_marble/download I always assumed that geotiffs contained any of the data I needed.

Comment: How do I go about "hand-cranking" the world file, if let's say I use differently sized JPG?

Comment: Also noticed that you are putting the JPG into a JMapFrame, and my project requires a map within a JMapPane. Is this possible, and if I am trying to add it to the map pane, is this the reason why it fails to appear in the pane, rather than what you say works in a frame?

Comment: Mapframe just puts it into a pane.

Comment: I've just tried it with your tif and they have a broken CRS (it's long/lat instead of lat/long) - you could probably fix it with gdaltransform but I'd just use the NASA ones which do work.

Comment: thanks for explaining why the geotiff didn't work. I am by no means a GIS expert, and it was above my head as to why it wouldn't work. The JPEG works, but reports that a CRS cannot be found, and GeoTools falls back to WG84. Can I use the data file for the image, to force it to a particular CRS?

Comment: you should be able to add a .proj file (download from epsg.io) in this case epsg:4326 and WGS84 are the same(ish).

Comment: Added a .prj file to the same directory containing the JPEG raster file (name the .prj file to match the JPEG name). Used the ESRI WKT format from here http://epsg.io/4326 -- CRS is now recognized by GeoTools.

Comment: Not getting the layers to correspond to one another. What is causing this? http://i.imgur.com/1HoiSyY.png

Comment: bad world file? - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file

Comment: Awesome, you rock =D. The jpw file you referenced was way off because I am using a different sized JPG. Anyhow, I used this site http://egb13.net/2009/03/worldfile-calculator/ to calculate the world file settings based on JPG dimensions.